# Obtaining data from ActorRef in akka

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I have the following Actor Model declaration in akka:

```
val wireA = system.actorOf(Props(new Wire(false)), "Input")
val wireB = system.actorOf(Props(new Wire(false)), "Output")
inverter ! generateOutput(wireA, wireB)
```

From the `generateOutput(input:ActorRef, output:ActorRef)`,
I need to access the `boolean` parameter which constructs each particular`ActorRef` (i.e the paramater `false` which is found in each respective `Wire` Constructor.

How does it can be reached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send a message to each actor, asking for its current status:

```
case object Status
case object StatusResult(value: Boolean)

class MyActor(wire: ActorRef) extends Actor {

  wire ! Status

  def receive = {
    case StatusResult(value) => ...
  }
```

`wireA` and `wireB` are `ActorRef`s, they do not expose their state and the only way to communicate with them is via messages.

Comment: Can you please explain it in more detail?
When I call input ! Status from the `generateOutput()` how can I utilize that message(`Boolean` value) to pass it to another actor? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's not the way you should play with Actors. You get the ActorRef and you you play with it only with the messages. You can ask the actor of the value of the boolean by passing a message to it:

wireA ! "getVal"

and waiting for the response in the sender actor. Please check the basic tutorial on Actors:

http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-akka-actors-ping-pong-simple-example